# How can I input text in a textarea using requests in python, and retrieve the html using bs4, when the input is seemingly in the background?

Tags: python, html, selenium, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to write a script that sends a string to https://lingojam.com/FancyTextGenerator and returns one or all of the "fancy text" variations the site gives. However, I can't quite figure out what the input area is in the HTML. If possible, I would like to send the information with requests—post instead of selenium.

My current code for sending and fetching what I input looks like this:

```py
def get_soup(input_text, URL)
    response = requests.post(URL, data={'english-text':input_text})
    data = response.text
    return BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

soup = get_soup('string', 'https://lingojam.com/FancyTextGenerator').find(contenteditable='plaintext-only')
```

Since the input seems to end up in a div tag with that attribute.

[image: HTML code for the TextArea tag]

(the white text translates to *"content in background(useragent)"*)

So, how can I send a POST/GET request to write in the text box and retrieve what comes up in the other textbox on the site, and if that is not possible, how can I do it with selenium?

Answer (score 0):

The textarea is being updated through JavaScript client-side, not server-side. So you can't get it with requests or BeautifulSoup.

Comment: Thank you, solved. Guess I'll try to manually make a similar script for the bot instead.